# Programmatically Trigger an inotify event on linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, inotify

Using shared folders on VirtualBox (or pretty much any VM) will not trigger inotify events on the guest OS when a file is changed on the host OS.

But if it's possible to programmatically trigger an inotify event then I can write a something (virtualbox plugin, client/server, etc) to tell linux (in this case Ubuntu) that the file has changed. This would allow any existing software that watches for file changes (ruby's guard, python's watchdog, node-watcher, etc) to work with shared folders and increase development speed.

language doesn't matter (but would prefer node given the ease of install across host OS's). if anyone knows how to accomplish would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: if what you are after isn't possible (idk), you could try doing a poll on a timer - so say every 10 seconds you list the contents in the directory and compare the date modified stamps manually.

Comment: appreciate the thought but guard, watcher, etc already have polling built in for exactly these types of situation. the problem with polling is that on on larger projects it's cpu intensive & can be very slow.

Comment: obvious question would be, you have the virtualbox tools/drivers installed on the guest vm, right?

Comment: thanks @SnakeDoc but inotify events do not fire on shared drives. explaination by virtualbox is here https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660. there is no situation in which you can make this happen. the only solution is to run listeners on the host and forward activity over to the guest and tap into what ever software you're using (ex: guard). but you have to write this for each software. if you can programmatically trigger an inotify even then these softwares will just work and no need to write a plugin for each one you want to use.

Comment: What if you mounted the share like a local device? You may have to use another hypervisor for that to work properly (KVM, Xen/XenServer, etc...). I think SAMBA supports inotify, not sure about other mounting methods.

Comment: 4 years later.  Here is what I do per OP request for nodejs.  Run on host/server   chokidar for directory watch + tcp socket, push when file changes.  On client/guest run tcp socket on same port and listen.  Then either by a config file or parsing /etc/mtab use answer below to trigger inotify on local file path.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '' -i filename
```

this command trigger an inotify change event but does not change the content of file

Answer (score 1):

`touch -r file.ext file.ext`

this will "update" the modification time of the file, but sets it to its own existing modification time. so, nothing is actually changed about the file or its metadata, yet `inotify` sees a "change".